# How to structure JSON to be sent over PHP's cURL

Tags: json, curl

I have an api which works fine when I use POSTMAN, but now that I am trying to send it with PHP I am getting an API error message in response.

> Format Error: The exception message is 'The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'

Which I am sure is related to my data structure. can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

**Header**

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

**JSON Body**

```
{
    "accessID": "ASASD22",
    "password": "DASD2DQA",
    "messages": [
        {
            "DestinationID": "22D2D2D22D",
            "UserMessageID": 133,
            "RawPayload": [1,31, 34, 43]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the PHP code I wrote, but returns an error code; can you guys see any issues?

```
$headers= array('Connection: Keep-Alive','Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8','Connection: Keep-Alive'); 

$data = array(
    "accessID" => "ASASD22",
    "password" => "DASD2DQA",
    "messages" =>  array(
    "DestinationID" => "22D2D2D22D",
    "UserMessageID" => "133",
    "RawPayload" => "[1,31, 34, 43]"
    )
);

$url_send ="http://api.SITE.com/RST-MESSAGE.svc/submit.json/";
$str_data = json_encode($data);

function sendPostData($url, $post){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

echo " " . sendPostData($url_send, $str_data);
```

Comment: *"but returns an error code"* -- what error code? Is it an HTTP error or an application error code?

Comment: sorry, no it's the api message - I will update the post

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to guess, you should check the API's documentation.

But, if the data posted as "JSON Body" is the request you send when it works then you should replicate it exactly in PHP (which you don't):

```
$data = array(
    "accessID" => "ASASD22",
    "password" => "DASD2DQA",
    "messages" =>  array(
        array(
            "DestinationID" => "22D2D2D22D",
            "UserMessageID" => "133",
            "RawPayload" => array(1, 31, 34, 43),
        ),
    )
);
```

I did two changes to your data structure. See below the pieces of `JSON body` that ask for changes in the structure of `$data`:

- `"messages": [ { ... } ]` - `messages` is an array of objects, not a single object;
- `"RawPayload": [1, 31, 34, 43]` - `RawPayload` is an array of integers, not a string;

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the errors but I still get the same message! "The exception message is 'The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw" - So I am pretty sure there is a problem with how I format the body Array

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to correctly send the entire JSON with in the PHP cURL function

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            "http://api.SITE.com/Messages.svc/submit.json/" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     '{
    "accessID": "ASASD22",
    "password": "DASD2DQA",
    "messages": [
        {
            "DestinationID": "22D2D2D22D",
            "UserMessageID": 133,
            "RawPayload": [1,31, 34, 43]
        }
            ]
    }' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json'));

$result=curl_exec ($ch);

echo $result;
?>
```

so basically I wrapped the entire JSON into `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data)` and send it that way!